# OneDrive Personal list versions API does not provide a unique id for the current version

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

I'm accessing OneDrive on a mobile app using the [msgraph iOS SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-objc). I want to allow the user to manage a file's versions and for that I'm using the [list versions API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-versions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs). In addition, I'm caching already downloaded files on the mobile device. I have encountered an issue with OneDrive personal, which behaves slightly different than OneDrive business concerning file versions.

It seems that when listing a file’s versions, personal assigns ‘current’ as the version id for the current version, whereas business sets an actual unique id. This behavior prevents me from assigning a unique identifier to the data that I cache on the device and so I can’t know whether there is a newer version on the backend that I should download.

I found a workaround which I feel is not the best solution - I'm using the file's `cTag` field. The documentation states that a `cTag` is:

> An eTag for the content of the item. This eTag is not changed if only the metadata is changed. Note This property is not returned if the item is a folder. Read-only.

Using the `cTag` as a unique id for the `current` version allows me to detect that a new version has been uploaded.

The reason I'm not happy with using it, is that the `cTag` is only available for the current version. On the other hand, the unique id is only available for non-current versions. Once a newer version is uploaded and an id is assigned to the previously current version, I have no way to know that I already downloaded this version and marked it with the previous `cTag`.

Is there a way that I could get a consistent unique identifier for a file's version? For example, if the `cTag` could somehow be made available in list versions API? Or, alternatively, get the unique id of the current version?

Thanks!